# Ruby error involving inject/method and hashes

Tags: ruby

Here is my array:

```
array = [{:url=>"http://jumpstartlab.com/blog", :respondedIn=>37},
 {:url=>"http://jumpstartlab.com/blog", :respondedIn=>1},
 {:url=>"http://jumpstartlab.com/blog", :respondedIn=>11},
 {:url=>"http://jumpstartlab.com/about", :respondedIn=>11}]
```

Here is my original method:

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, ele| hash[ele[:url]] += ele[:respondedIn]}
```

Here is my error message:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

This is what I wanted returned:

```
{"http://jumpstartlab.com/blog"=>49, "http://jumpstartlab.com/about"=>11}
```

This is the working code:

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, ele| hash[ele[:url]] += ele[:respondedIn]; hash}
```

What is going wrong with my original method? Why did it throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

When using `inject`, after the first call to your block, each successive call gets *the return value of the previous one* as its accumulator.  So you have to return the hash from the block:

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, ele| hash[ele[:url]] += ele[:respondedIn]; hash}
```

You could use `Hash#merge` and avoid the extra statement in the block:

```
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, ele| 
  hash.merge({ ele[:url] => hash[ele[:url]] +  ele[:respondedIn] })
end
```

Or, as Cary Swoveland suggests, you could use `each_with_object`, which handles mutable accumulators more cleanly.  Note that it passes the object to the block *after* the current item instead of before it, however:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new 0) { |ele, hash| hash[ele[:url]] += ele[:respondedIn] }
```

Any of those yields your desired result:

```
# => {"http://jumpstartlab.com/blog"=>49, "http://jumpstartlab.com/about"=>11}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first try, you are not returning the correct value for the inject block. The inject block needs the accumulated value of the initial value, in your case `Hash.new`, as the return value. `hash[ele[:url]] += ele[:respondedIn]` statement does not return the hash. I will demonstrate the difference with an example.

```
def first_try(hash,value)
  hash[value] += value
end

h1 = {1 => 1, 2 => 2}
first_try(h1,1) # => 2
first_try(h1,2) # => 4
```

In the first_try, I'm returning the last statement in the same way you did in your inject block. You can check the return value. It's just the result of the calculation. I'm not getting the hash back.

```
def second_try(hash,value)
  hash[value] += value
  hash
end

h2 = {1 => 1, 2 => 2}
second_try(h2,1) # => {1=>2, 2=>2}
second_try(h2,2) # => {1=>2, 2=>4}
```

In the second try, I'm explicitly returning the hash. So I get it back.

You can modify the code like Mark Reed has mentioned to avoid the explicit return.